# Rolling mean of zeros not returning zeros as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I use the following function to calculate the rolling mean over 4 rows and use the returned value in the denominator of some ratios (in my case, 4 rows represent 4 quarters of the year):

```
def mean_year(var):
    mean_year = var.rolling(min_periods=1, window=4).mean()
    return mean_year
```

However, I am finding something really odd, whereby, if the column has all zeros, the mean_year value returned is not 0. Instead, the values being return are negative. E.g. 3.41061e-13.

I created this `df` to test what was going on:

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((20, 2)), columns=list('AB'))`

`df['C'] = mean_year(df['A'])`

Column `C` returns all zeros as you would expect. All the columns are float64 in my dataset too. Any ideas of why it would not return 0 when all the values in the  column are 0 would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It is a scientific notation to represent value. Try rounding off the value of mean and apply to your dataframe.

```
def mean_year(var):
    mean_year = var.rolling(min_periods=1, window=4).mean().round(2)
    return mean_year
```

you can also set the pandas display option for float to two decimal point

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
```